# Global sections and Fiber products $X \times_S \operatorname{Spec} k$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X $ a $S$-scheme ($S$ another scheme). Suppose $k$ is a field
and $S$ has a $k$-valued point, that is a map
$p: \operatorname{Spec} k \to S$. If $X \times_S \operatorname{Spec} k$
denotes the associated fiber product, can we say something
interesting about global sections
$H^0(X \times_S \operatorname{Spec} k, \mathcal{O}_{X \times_S \operatorname{Spec} k})$
if we know global sections of $X $ and $S$?

Say for sake of simplicity that $S= \operatorname{Spec}(A)$ is also affine
and $k$ corresponds to some prime ideal of $A$. Then the structure sheaf of
$X \times_S \operatorname{Spec} k$ is $O_X \otimes_A k$. Now if we come
back to global sections of $X \times_S \operatorname{Spec} k$ can we
pull out $k$ from
$H^0(X \times_S \operatorname{Spec} k, \mathcal{O}_X \otimes_A k)$ and
reduce the calculation to global sections of $X$?

Altoght the question seems to arise quite naturally it seems to require (at least if we deal with general fiber products $X \times_S Y$) advanced tools to find answers like in [this discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34673/kunneth-formula-for-sheaf-cohomology-of-varieties).
That's why I take here for $Y$ a field as the most simple choice with hope to find out if my question can be answered by methods from on 'non research' level.

If the answer is negative, are there any sufficient conditions when $H^0(X \times_S \operatorname{Spec} k, \mathcal{O}_{X \times_S \operatorname{Spec} k})= H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_{X}) \otimes_A k $?

Comment: You might be looking for something like [flat base change](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02KH) (the case $i = 0$ in the second part of the above gives global sections when using $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{O}_{X}$ as coefficient.

Comment: so $p$ flat is the *weakest* assumption one can do to garantee that the equality above holds? That says also that in almost all cases when we consider non generic fibers this fails...

Comment: I don't know if that's the weakest assumption, it's just one sufficient assumption I'm aware of

Answer (score 4):

**Question:** "If the answer is negative, are there any sufficient conditions when $H^0(X×_{S} Spec(k),O_{X×_S Spec(k)})=H^0(X,O_X)⊗_A k$?"

**Answer:** In the affine case you get the following calculation: If $\phi: X:=Spec(B) \rightarrow S:=Spec(A)$ is a map and $i: T:=Spec(k) \rightarrow S$ is a $k$-rational point it follows $T\times_S X:=Spec(k\otimes_A B)$ and it follows

$$H^0(T\times_S X, \mathcal{O}_{T\times_S X})=k\otimes_A B\cong k\otimes_A H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_X).$$

Hence your formula is correct for affine schemes. It is not correct in general.

Comment: Yes, the affine case works always because for affine schemes $X=Spec(A), Y=Spec(B), S=Spec(R)$ the scheme theoretic fiber product $X \times_S Y$ is also affine and equals $Spec(A \otimes_R B)$. What about a more interesting case if $X$ is *not affine*?

Comment: I mean you are absolutelly right the affine case is literally *sufficient* and your
answer is fine. If you
want I can accept this answer and open a separate new question asking the same
question but explicitely 
for the case when $X$ is *not affine*, since initially that what I wanted
to discuss but forgot to remark that the affine case is known and not really interesting.
Or do you want to expand your answer to a discussion where $H^0 $ commutes with
$k$ for $X$ not affine?

Answer (score 2):

We may assume that $S=\mathrm{Spec}R$ for a DVR $R$ with residue field $k$ and a uniformizer $\pi$ and $X$ is a scheme flat over $R$.
Then $\mathcal{O}_X$ is $R$-torsion-free so there is a short exact sequence
$$
0\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X\overset{\times \pi}{\rightarrow}\mathcal{O}_X\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X_k}\rightarrow 0.
$$
Taking the global section, we obtain an injection
$$H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\otimes_{R}k=H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X)/\pi H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\hookrightarrow H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_{X_k}),$$
which is not necessarily surjective. Therefore, in such a case, if the $\pi$-torsion part of $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is trivial then you obtain the desired isomorphism.